# Disable automatically adding closing parenthesis

Tags: webstorm

Somehow on my laptop, [[image]webstorm](/questions/tagged/webstorm) is now autocompleting parentheses.  I can't find the setting to disable it.

For example, if I type `myCustomFunction(` it will instantly add `)`.  I don't like this.

Where is the setting to disable it?

Here is a simple gif. Note that I'm *never* hitting `enter` or `tab`.  If someone can recommend software that might do a screencast and show keyboard input I could make a better one.

[image]

Comment: Any chance for a small screencast? -- maybe we can spot some nuances... But in general -- just typing the whole function name (and not pressing any other shortcuts) should not insert `()` -- it may only be added this way when using code completion popup.

Comment: Added gif, hope it helps. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: Well -- that's a code completion popup -- absolutely expected in such case behaviour. It's still not clear what key did you pressed when you have finished to type `test` though -- was it `Enter` or `Tab` or something else? For `Tab` or `Enter` it's absolutely expected behaviour. Some other keys are also viable here. If you do not like code completion popup -- disable it at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Code Completion` -- you can still invoke it manually at any time by pressing `Ctrl+Space` (or whatever else you may have there on your computer for `Code | Completion | Basic`)

Comment: As stated in my edit, I am not hitting tab or enter at all.  Only `test(`.  I definitely don't want to disable code completion.  This does not happen on my desktop at work.

Answer (score 0):

In `Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys`, try disabling `Insert pair bracket`

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't do it.

Comment: please record a screencast then

Comment: I just realized this happens at work too, so I think it's always happened.  The difference is that on my laptop it moves the cursor *outside* of the parenthesis (as seen in the gif).  At work it leaves the cursor inside, which is fine, of course.

Comment: @ScottBeeson Compare your code completion settings then; as well as `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys`. P.S. Please also ensure that you are checking it on the same code sample (at both home and work).